# How parse key-value with regex

Tags: java, regex

i use Kotlin \ Java for parse some string.

My regex:
`\[\'(.*?)[\]]=\'(.*?)(?!\,)[\']`

text for parse:

`someArray1['key1'] = 'value1', someArray2['key2'] = 'value2', ignoreText=ignore, some['key3'] = 'value3', ignoreMe['ignore']=ignore, some['key4'] = 'value4'..`

i need result:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
key4=value4
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you doing this in Java, Javascript or Kotlin?

Comment: i am doing this in Kotlin and Java, also i try js and regex101.com, but it not found all mathes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another regex for you

```
\['(\w+)'\]\s+(=)\s+'(\w+)'
```

[**Regex101 Demo Fiddle**](https://regex101.com/r/ubMQUw/1)

Java test code

```
    String str = "someArray1['key1'] = 'value1', someArray2['key2'] = 'value2', ignoreText=ignore, some['key3'] = 'value3', ignoreMe['ignore']=ignore, some['key4'] = 'value4'..";
    String regex = "\\['(\\w+)'\\]\\s+(=)\\s+'(\\w+)'";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2) + matcher.group(3));
    }
```

Test result:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
key4=value4
```

Answer (score 2):

A few notes about the pattern that you tried

- In your pattern you are not matching the spaces around the equals sign.
- Also note that this part `(?!\,)[\']` will always work as it says that it asserts not a comma to the right, and then matches a single quote.
- You don't have to escape the `\'` and the single characters do not have to be in a character class.
- You can use a pattern with a negated character class to capture the values between the single quotes to prevent `.*?` matching too much as the dot can match any character.

You might write the pattern as

```
\['([^']*)'\]\h+=\h+'([^']*)'
```

The pattern matches:

- `\['` Match `['`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^']*` Match optional chars other than `'`
- `)` Close group 1
- `'\]` Match `']`
- `\h+=\h+` Match an equals sign between 1 or more horizontal whitespace characters
- `'([^']*)'` Capture **group 2** which has the same pattern as group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4vwToS/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/3H1uoe)

Example

```
String regex = "\\['([^']*)'\\]\\h+=\\h+'([^']*)'";
String string = "someArray1['key1'] = 'value1', someArray2['key2'] = 'value2', ignoreText=ignore, some['key3'] = 'value3', ignoreMe['ignore']=ignore, some['key4'] = 'value4'..";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + "=" + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
key4=value4
```

Comment: good job! thanks for pointing out my mistakes, I broke my brain in the hope of understanding what I was doing wrong